# Ransomware's effect on google cloud storage

Tags: cloud, storage

Can you please let me know if google cloud storage has pre checks for Malwares like ransomware?

If the infected file got uploaded to the storage bucket , will it infect the entire bucket? I mean will the ransomware spreads like it does on Windows box.

Thanks in advance

Sourabh

Comment: Anyone please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any such case till date. Ransomware isn't infected on the cloud till date. Of course, it has cracked the smart home applications in various hotels and hospitals but the cloud is something which I haven't heard about.

I always keep an eye on latest Ransomware because I love to research about them. I will surely let you know if there's something released or dangerous for the cloud. Be it a Google Cloud or any other cloud service. As of now, it's hard to bypass the security walls of the cloud for Ransomware, but sooner or later, I believe it's going to happen!